# How to unselect items in a ListView when clicking a button

Tags: listview, kotlin, selector

I have a listview with list selector, and I was wondering if it is possible to have a button to unselect the item and leave the list with no item selected (I want to remove just the Highlight bar, not the item).

this is my listview config:

```
        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="386dp"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray"

    </ListView>
```

I was thinking of something like:

```
   btn1.setOnClickListener {
    listView1.listselector = false

}
```

Thank you in advance for ur support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change the ListView's choiceMode and reassign the adapter:

```
btn1.setOnClickListener {
    listView1.choiceMode = ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE
    listView1.adapter = adapter
}
```

but if you just want to clear the selected item
`listView1.adapter = adapter` is enough

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!